# no error message in php

Tags: php, error-handling

PHP does not display any error messages. for example :

```
<?php
    require 'connect.php';

    if(isset($_GET['last_name'] ,$_GET['first_name'])){

        $last_name = trim($_GET['last_name']);
        $first_name = trim($_GET['first_name']);

        $people = $db->prepare("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM people
            WHERE last_name=?");
        $people = $db->bind_param('s',$last_name);//s for data type string 
        $people->execute();

        $people->bind_results($first_name,$last_name);

        while($people->fetch()){
            echo $first_name. ' '.$last_name.'<br>';
        }

        echo $first_name;
    }
?>
```

this program has an error bind_results should be bind_result, for some reason it doesn't show me php errors. 
Also i have tried the following : `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

and in php.ini the display_errors is on

Comment: are you using the right php.ini ? in some distributions and version there is one for the command line and one for apache. Add a " ini_set('display_errors', '1');" to find out

Comment: adding ini_set('display_errors', '1') didnt help @ElvisCiotti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put this inmediatly after the php tag (line 2), (also in your connect.php file):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
```

Comment: Looks like is an error php cant detect. Does the program stop running on "$people->bind_results($first_name,$last_name)" or finish running with weird results?

Comment: it finish running and displays a blank page. its weird everything in the php.ini seems to be correct @gftp

Comment: try changing this: if((isset($_GET['last_name'])  && isset($_GET['first_name']))){ // your code looks wrong here. Sometimes, some buggy code runs. Also, put an  *else { echo "there"; }* statement for every place to trace it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't seem to get error reporting to display to your screen, you may have 
[log_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) set in your `php.ini` file.

One thing you can try is to run your PHP script through a command line.

```
$bash: php script.php
```

This should tell you the errors that the browser is concealing.

Comment: is it possible to fix the php.ini @Quixrick

Comment: Yes, it's entirely possible if you have access to it.  You'll want to check a couple of things.  1. Is `log_errors` on?  2. Also, check the `error_log` setting to see where the errors are currently being sent.  This would be a better idea than displaying them to the screen anyway.  You can just `tail -f YOUR_LOGFILE_HERE.log` to see any errors that are being generated.

Comment: thank you for your help,  log errors is on still doesn't display errors

Comment: Yeah, I'm not certain, but I think if `log_errors` is on, then it won't display them.  Check to see where it is sending them.  Use the location set in `error_log`.  Did it work using the command line to see the errors?  `$bash: php script_that_generates_errors.php`